# $\binom{2n}{n} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

Let a prime $p$ such that $1 \leq n <p<2n$. Prove that:

$$\binom{2n}{n} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

Can I do it like that?

$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2) \cdots (2n-1)2n}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots n}\overset{ \text{As } 1 \leq n <p<2n }{=} \frac{(n+1)(n+2) \cdots p \cdots (2n-1)2n}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots n} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

Comment: You should use a couple of words. But mostly yes.

Comment: What could I write for example?

Comment: you need to get rid of the denominator

Comment: But..it is not equal to something from the numerator..I got rid from the first $n!$,isn't it right??

Comment: "Since $p < 2n$, $p$ divides the numerator, but since $p > n$, it doesn't divide the denominator."

Comment: adding to @DanielFischer's answer, $\binom{2n}{n}$ is always an integer. (wait,what's the proof)

Comment: @DanielFischer I think one needs more than that, being prime is also important. Note that $6$ divides the numerator of $4=\frac{12}{3}$ and it doesn't divide the denominator....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the last line needs a justification, note that the fact that $p$ is a prime is the key here.

Note that when you say 
$$ \frac{(n+1)(n+2) \cdots p \cdots (2n-1)2n}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots n} \equiv 0 \pmod p \,,$$
you say that  $\frac{(n+1)(n+2) \cdots (p-1)(p+1) \cdots (2n-1)2n}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots n}$ is integer, but why is that the case?

The argument is very simple:
$$\binom{2n}{n} n! =(n+1)(n+2) \cdots p \cdots (2n-1)2n$$

Therefore $p$ divides $\binom{2n}{n} n!$. As $p$ is prime, we get $p| \binom{2n}{n}$ or $p|n!$. But $p|n!$ is not possible, as again primality would imply that it divides one of $1,2,3,...,n$.

Comment: I understood the argument!!! But,could you explain me why:

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+1) \cdots (p-1)(p+1) \cdots (2n-1)2n}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots n}$$
is not an integer??

Comment: @evinda It is an integer, but it is not OBVIOUS that it is an integer. In other words, can you explain why IS an integer?? Note that explaining why is an integer is exactly the justification of this last step.

Comment: @evinda And just to clarify something, it is an integer when $p$ is prime, but if $n< p< 2n$ is not prime sometimes $\frac{(n+1)(n+1) \cdots (p-1)(p+1) \cdots (2n-1)2n}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots n}$ is not an integer. For example, it is not an integer when $n=4, p=6$.... And this makes the justification needed, at least in my opinion.

Comment: But how can I show that it is an integer,when $p$ is a prime?

And could you explain me further why it is not an integer,when $p$ is not a prime?

Comment: @evinda Check my answer, since $\frac{(n+1)(n+1) \cdots (p-1)(p+1) \cdots (2n-1)2n}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots n} =\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{p}$, the moment I proved that $p | \binom{2n}{n}$ I implicitly proved that this is an integer. But this is not needed, $p | \binom{2n}{n}$ means $\binom{2n}{n} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$... As for non-primes, this is not needed, but if you want to see it for curiosity, calculate that fraction with $n=4, p=6$....

Comment: Ok,I understand...thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Lucas' theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lucas-theorem/) solved this immediately:
$$\binom{n}{i} \equiv \binom{2n-p}{n}\binom{1}{0} \equiv 0 \pmod{p},$$
because $2n-p<n$.